# exclude subdomain of rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have my main site with the next .htaccess

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

and in my subdomain i just install wordpress, but the rewrite rules of my main site broke the navigation of my wordpress, how can exclude my subdomain from the rules of my main domain?

i am try this but dont work

```
# don't apply any rewrites to the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

and in the .htaccess of my wordpress forlder i have this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

any idea how can fix this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use in your main site .htaccess

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```